# why my Javacomplete doesn't work without sudo privileges?

Tags: java, linux, vim, autocomplete, vim-plugin

I'm a vim beginner and i installed [Javacomplete2](https://github.com/artur-shaik/vim-javacomplete2) (a updated version of javacomplete) as well as  [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) for auto completion.

However JC2 doesn't work unless i use `sudo gvim` to start gVim

Every time i press <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-o</kbd> to call omnifunc, I get

`-- Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found`

I installed JC2 through [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug):

`Plug 'artur-shaik/vim-javacomplete2'`

my .vimrc:

`autocmd Filetype java setlocal omnifunc=javacomplete#Complete`

p.s.: ive tried a fresh .vimrc but nothing changed

### Update

i found that JC2 can partly work without sudo:

Comparison (sorry im using the chinese version;D)

as u can see, JC2 doesn't work for the first two situation without sudo

`import java|`
[image]

`List list = new Li|`
[image]

`list.|`
[image]

Comment: Where is your .vimrc?

Comment: @romainl ive already talked about this... 1. settings on jc2 is  simply set the omnifunc. 2. I've tried a fresh vimrc, so it can't be problem on bimrc

Comment: @rundis: Instead of being rude you should answer romainl question which isn't "what is in your vimrc" but "where did you put it". If your vimrc is in a file owned by root of where your user doesn't have sufficient permissions it might be a cause of your problem.

Comment: @statox sorry for misunderstanding. my .vimrc is in /home/my-user-name